# Potential fat in wort, what's going to happen?

Tags: contamination, off-flavor, head-retention

I had some bad luck the other day and half way through my boil a small but significant amount of water fell in my brew from my extractor fan. I haven't given the extractor a good clean in a while and since I was in the boil stage I am not concerned about contamination, I am aware however there is probably a significant amount of grease up there that could have mixed with the water before dripping back into the kettle.

I finished up the batch anyway and its been fermenting happily a few days. What detrimental affects might be on the cards for my brew? a friend tells me fat certainly isn't a brewers friend.

Comment: If you were boiling hops in the kettle when this happened then any oils/fats/molten grease would tend to stick to the hop leaves or the side of the kettle. I don't think much would remain in the wort to be transferred to the brew bin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The worst that could happen is that it would affect head formation and retention.  But you might be OK.  No big deal.

Answer (score 3):

That grease in extraction fan is from volatile food grease / oils. In my experience these are not water soluable. The condensation that fell back in was most likely just water.